# Do some areas of math have worse problems?

Tags: soft-question

I really love Godel and logic, but it seems to me that most books are heavy on theory and light on problems. It also seems to me that this isn't just a fluke -- there really is something about logic that makes it tougher to approach via problems, rather than reading theory.

What I'm wondering is: is it true? Do some areas of math really have worse problems? Why would that be, and what areas of math are most afflicted with this plight?

Comment: I think obviously, yes, some areas of mathematics (e.g. calculus, combinatorics) yield themselves much more readily to computational problems than others (e.g. topology).

Comment: But problems need not be computational, right? For example regular old plane geometry contains a wealth of non-computational proof problems.

Comment: true, though if you count proofs as problems, it's not clear to me why logic shouldn't have as many as other subjects

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it depends on what you mean "worse problems." Number theory has something as simple as Goldbach's conjecture, which  you could state to a grade school child, but has yet to be proven. Again, topology has the "inscribed square problem," which is almost equally easy to state, again, has an illusive proof. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem